# I want to move in my navigation bar in a non gimmicky way

Tags: html, css, navigation, positioning

I'm quite very new to HMTL and CSS, having just coded in C# before.

I got this fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/4asrj9x6/24/

```
<html>
  <header>

    <body>
      <nav>
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="grid">
    <aside></aside>
    <section>
      <h1>Header</h1>      
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x350.jpg">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Aenean pharetra magna ac
        placerat vestibulum. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
        diam in arcu. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Sit amet mauris
        commodo quis imperdiet massa. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Header</h1>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350.jpg">        
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Aenean pharetra magna ac
        placerat vestibulum. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
        diam in arcu. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Sit amet mauris
        commodo quis imperdiet massa. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper.
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Header</h1>      
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/620x350.jpg">       
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
        dolore magna aliqua. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Aenean pharetra magna ac
        placerat vestibulum. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
        diam in arcu. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Sit amet mauris
        commodo quis imperdiet massa. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper.
      </p>
    </section>
    <aside></aside>
  </main>

  </body>

</html>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  margin-top: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 8px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.24));
  background-color: whitesmoke;

}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
li a{
     display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

aside {
  margin: none;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
}

section img:hover {
  opacity: 50%;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

section p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to move in my nav bar links from the right edge. So that the end of 'About' is sort of aligned with the end of the third image.

What I've tried is to add a lot of padding to the navigation class. However this feels super gimmicky and it doesn't scale well at all. Since as soon as you move the window even a tiny bit it goes all wrong.

There should be a better way to do this but I feel kind of stuck.

Comment: You have invalid markup in your HTML in your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4asrj9x6/24/) There is no `</headers>` tag and also with the above the `<header>...</header>` MUST be within the `body` section rather than the `body` element beginning in the `header`. These sort of layout/nesting issues can and will affect layout and likely cause you to struggle with alignment

Comment: thanks, that was just a problem from moving it from my vs code to the fiddle. I fixed it though!

Comment: The above HTML code  still displays the same mistake. The `<body>` tag ***must*** be before the `<header>` tag. The `<head><title></title></head>` elements are not option if you want valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give your nav-bar a width to work with, since you have `justify-content` set to `flex-end` it will always be on the end depending on the width you have set.

Give your nav-bar a reasonable width and line in up with the third image.

Final code:

```
header nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 100%;
    width: --your-desirable-width;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is responsable and it'll always be ..% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

so this should be what you are looking for, I have used css position: sticky; and have added only 2 lines of code in the styling of the header

```html
<html>

  <body>
  
  <style> 
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  margin-top: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 8px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.24));
  background-color: whitesmoke;
 
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
li a{
     display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation li {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

aside {
  margin: none;
}

section h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
}

section img:hover {
  opacity: 50%;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

section p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
 
 </style>
    <header>


      <nav>
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="grid">
      <aside></aside>
      <section>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x350.jpg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Aenean pharetra magna ac
          placerat vestibulum. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
          diam in arcu. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Sit amet mauris
          commodo quis imperdiet massa. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350.jpg">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Aenean pharetra magna ac
          placerat vestibulum. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
          diam in arcu. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Sit amet mauris
          commodo quis imperdiet massa. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/620x350.jpg">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliqua. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Aenean pharetra magna ac
          placerat vestibulum. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas
          diam in arcu. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Sit amet mauris
          commodo quis imperdiet massa. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper.
        </p>
      </section>
      <aside></aside>
    </main>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: pls upvote it if you think it works an its proper

Comment: i have made it super easy and i have literally added 2 lines of code